promiseToFuture never returns
I have the following Flutter code:
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:js_util';
[...]
final ScriptElement script = ScriptElement()
  ..async = true
  ..src = "assets/lib/myjscode.js";
querySelector('head')!.children.add(script);

await script.onLoad.first;

var jsRes = js.context.callMethod('initJS');
// The following call prints "In promise resolve"
// but then blocks indefinitely
var pr = await promiseToFuture(jsRes); 

// This line of code is never reached
print("Complete")

and the following Javascript code:
async function initJS() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("In promise resolve")
            resolve('test');
        }, 2000);
      });
}

When I run the dart code, I see In promise resolve is displayed in the console (in VS code), but the call to promiseToFuture never returns. In Chrome, when opening the development tools, I also see In promise resolve displayed, and no error.
I am lost as to what is happening - no exception, no error displayed in the console, no return from the function. What am I doing wrong?
I tried with both Flutter 3.22.0 and 3.19.6.

This issue can be because of the asynchronous nature of the JavaScript Promise
Your js function creates a promise that resolves after 2 seconds with the value test. Then you  call promiseToFuture on the js promise object.promiseToFuture waits for the Promise to resolve or reject. However, the Dart code execution continues after calling promiseToFuture.Since the Dart code continues, the print("Complete") line gets scheduled for execution after the promiseToFuture call. But because the Promise hasn't resolved yet it takes 2 seconds, the await keyword in await promiseToFuture(jsRes) pauses the execution of the current function until the Promise resolves.

The print("Complete") line never gets executed. Even if I'm waiting 10 seconds.

Note that even ìf I omit the await, eg. I type var pr = promiseToFuture(jsRes);, print("Complete") never gets executed either.
